# JAVA Kafka consumer API with multiple brokers do not return all messages

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a simple JAVA Kafka consumer code using JAVA kafka-client 2.0.0 API. I have a single topic with 30 partitions (3 replicas) on a cluster with 3 brokers. I used Kafka console producer to publish messages on the kafka topic and ensured that all partitions (and their replicas) have messages in them. A single message is 550 KB

I am trying to consume the messages using the JAVA Consumer API for Kafka.

`properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"server1:9092,server2:9092,server3:9092");`

I have this property setup to limit the amount of data returned in a single fetch.

`properties.setProperty("max.partition.fetch.bytes", "500000");`   --> 500 KB

What I noticed is that the response only returns data from 10 partitions and not all 30. I suspect that it's somehow using the first broker in the cluster instead of all 3. Does the Java Consumer for Kafka use all 3 brokers while making a fetch request? Ideally, I should only get a single message from each partition since the "max.partition.fetch.bytes" (500 KB) is less than the size of a single message (550 KB). However, I only get 10 messages from 10 partitions instead of total 30 messages, one from each partition.

Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: just for clarification: do you have 10 partitions which a replication factor of 3 or do you have 30 partitions with a replication factor of 3?

Comment: 30 partitions with 3 replicas/partition